Unable to create multiple azurerm_api_management_api using for_each loop
I am unable to create multiple api's under one API management GW. Each API has same backend but different open api document. Below is my code. Not sure the error which i am getting is because of my logic that i used in the loop or is it because of the provider version.
main.tf

resource "azurerm_api_management" "apim" {
  name                 = "azdlgleuw-apim-bhaskar-007"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  location             = "west Europe"
  publisher_name       = "sharat"
  publisher_email      = "abcde@xyz.com"
  virtual_network_type = "Internal"
  sku_name             = "Developer_1"

  virtual_network_configuration {
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.api-subnet.id
    }

  depends_on = [azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.apim-subnet-nsg,azurerm_public_ip.api-pip]

  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.api-pip.id
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {
  for_each = var.apimanagementapi
  name                = each.value["name"]
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  revision            = each.value["revision"]
  display_name        = each.value["display_name"]
  path                = each.value["path"]
  protocols           = each.value["protocols"]

  import {
    content_format = "openapi"
    content_value  = file("${path.module}/${each.value["content_value"]}")
  }
}

Policy management for API
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "example" {
  for_each = var.apimanagementapi
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi[each.key].name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name

  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service base-url="https://functionapp-001.azurewebsites.net/api" />
    
  </inbound>
</policies>
XML
}

var.tf
        
variable "apimanagementapi" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
      apimanagementapi_1 = {
        name                = "bhaskar-import-api-001"
        revision            = "1"
        display_name        = "sharat-latestAPI"
        path                = "extranet/v1"
        protocols           = ["https"]
        content_value       = "ExtranetAPIopenapi.yaml"
      },
      apimanagementapi_2 = {
        name                = "bhaskar-import-moreapi-001"
        revision            = "1"
        display_name        = "bhaskar-latestAPI"
        path                = "ext/v2"
        protocols           = ["https"]
        content_value       = "moreapi.yaml"
      },
      apimanagementapi_3 = {
        name                = "bhaskar-import-newapi-001"
        revision            = "1"
        display_name        = "nan-latestAPI"
        path                = "ex/v3"
        protocols           = ["https"]
        content_value       = "newapi.yaml"
      }
  } 
}

I have all these content value files in my directory.
Error:
│ Error: creating/updating Api (Subscription: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
│ Resource Group Name: "azdlgleuw-rg-bhaskarapigw-001"
│ Service Name: "azdlgleuw-apim-bhaskar-007"
│ Api: "bhaskar-import-moreapi-001;rev=1"): polling after CreateOrUpdate: executing request: unexpected status 404 (404 Not Found) with error: ResourceNotFound: Api not found.
│
│   with azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi["apimanagementapi_2"],
│   on main.tf line 318, in resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi":
│  318: resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {
│
│ Error: creating/updating Api (Subscription: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
│ Resource Group Name: "azdlgleuw-rg-bhaskarapigw-001"
│ Service Name: "azdlgleuw-apim-bhaskar-007"
│ Api: "bhaskar-import-newapi-001;rev=1"): polling after CreateOrUpdate: executing request: unexpected status 404 (404 Not Found) with error: ResourceNotFound: Api not found.
│
│   with azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi["apimanagementapi_3"],
│   on main.tf line 318, in resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi":
│  318: resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {


What is the provider version and the Terraform version you're using?

Where is azdlgleuw-apim-bhaskar-007 coming from? I can't find that string in the code you provided.

@RuiJarimba "azdlgleuw-apim-bhaskar-007" is my api management name. Let me add that as well in above code. Also note that i am using provider version 3.90.0

Add azurerm_resource_group block as I have given below and access it while deploying the code.
And also use below latest release azurerm provider for deployment.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.99.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "windows-function-rg"{
    name = "xxxx"
}
resource "azurerm_api_management" "apim" {
  name                 = "sampleapimjah"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
  location             = "west Europe"
  publisher_name       = "sharat"
  publisher_email      = "abcde@xyz.com"
 # virtual_network_type = "Internal"
  sku_name             = "Developer_1"
}
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "sharatapimgmntapi" {
      for_each = var.apimanagementapi
      name                = each.value["name"]
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name
      api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
      revision            = each.value["revision"]
      display_name        = each.value["display_name"]
      path                = each.value["path"]
      protocols           = each.value["protocols"]
}
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "example" {
  for_each = var.apimanagementapi
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.sharatapimgmntapi[each.key].name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.apim.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.windows-function-rg.name

  xml_content = <<XML
<policies>
  <inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service base-url="https://sharattes-functionapp-001.azurewebsites.net/api" />
  </inbound>
</policies>
XML
}

var.tf:
variable "apimanagementapi" {
      type = map(any)
      default = {
          apimanagementapi_1 = {
            name                = "bhaskar-import-api-001"
            revision            = "1"
            display_name        = "sharat-latestAPI"
            path                = "extranet/v1"
            protocols           = ["https"]
            content_value       = "ExtranetAPIopenapi.yaml"
          },
          apimanagementapi_2 = {
            name                = "bhaskar-import-moreapi-001"
            revision            = "1"
            display_name        = "bhaskar-latestAPI"
            path                = "ext/v2"
            protocols           = ["https"]
            content_value       = "moreapi.yaml"
          },
          apimanagementapi_3 = {
            name                = "bhaskar-import-newapi-001"
            revision            = "1"
            display_name        = "nan-latestAPI"
            path                = "ex/v3"
            protocols           = ["https"]
            content_value       = "newapi.yaml"
          }
      } 
    }




which policy documents did you use?

it still throws the same error message. Even now i am using the latest provider version

I have executed the same code as you with a few modifications and it worked. @SharatBhaskar

I am having the same problem, any clue? MY module
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "api" {
  name                  = lower(replace(var.api_settings.name, " ", "-"))
  description           = var.api_settings.description
  resource_group_name   = var.resource_group_name
  api_management_name   = var.api_management_name
  service_url           = var.api_settings.service_url
  revision              = var.api_settings.revision
  display_name          = var.api_settings.name
  path                  = var.api_settings.basepath
  protocols             = ["https"]
  subscription_required = var.api_settings.subscription_required

  soap_pass_through = var.soap_pass_through

  import {
    content_format = "openapi" 
    content_value  = file(var.api_settings.openapi_file_path)
  }
}

